# How to run external blackbox tests from Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Suppose I have a Rust program with some blackbox tests written in sh or Python (for example). Is there any easy way to get `Cargo test` to run them?

(I realize this is a bit against the grain of Cargo, since it's likely to introduce untracked dependencies on OS tools. But it'd be really useful, since I have some existing tests I want to reuse.)

Comment: Example code doing this: https://github.com/sourcefrog/conserve/blob/master/tests/run_cram.rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick-and-dirty tests, you can run external executables by way of a shell command with [std::process::Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html). Simply stick it into the tests directory, as so:

```
#[test]
fn it_works() {
    use std::process::Command;

    let output = Command::new("python.exe")
        .arg("test.py")
        .output()
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| { panic!("failed to execute process: {}", e) });

    let s = match String::from_utf8(output.stdout) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
    };

    println!("result: {}", s); //must run "cargo test -- --nocapture" to see output
}
```

For anything more complicated than that, you will have to use a FFI specific to the external language.

Comment: Thanks! Incidentally that argument is now `cargo test -- --nocapture`, but it will show the output by default if the test fails.